# Not able to Convert Array of Json to Flattern Json Using Jolt (V0.1.1)

Tags: java, arrays, json, apache-nifi, jolt

**Input payload:**

```json
{
  "accountNo":112233,
  "type":"DEDICATED",
  "Plans" : {
     "One":"Basic",
     "Two":"Mid",
     "Three":"Premium"  
   },

  "Address": {
     "Primary":{
       "Addressline1":" road 1, boss lane",
      "AddressLine2": "ST",
    "City":"Tex"
    }
  }

}
```

**Expected PayLoad:**

```json
{
  "accountNo":112233,
  "type":"DEDICATED",
  "One":"Basic",
  "Two":"Mid",
  "Three":"Premium",
  "Addressline1":" road 1, boss lane",
  "AddressLine2": "ST",
  "City":"Tex"
}
```

Used Jolt v0.1.1
not able to convert , could anyone help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can individually evaluate the expression by seperating into the conditional branches of `Plans`, `Address.Primary` and `*` for the rest(*non-nested*) of the elements within a **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Plans": {
        "*": "&"
      },
      "Address": {
        "Primary": {
          "*": "&"
        }
      },
      "*": {
        "@": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: is There any tool which will generate Spec based input Json?

Comment: Hi @Shivak, there's a famous online [playground](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception) .

Answer (score 0):

Check this spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "accountNo": "accountNo",
      "type": "type",
      "Plans": {
        "One": "One",
        "Two": "Two",
        "Three": "Three"
      },
      "Address": {
        "Primary": {
          "Addressline1": "Addressline1",
          "AddressLine2": "AddressLine2",
          "City": "City"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```